# React components not being instantiated

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js

I have an array of data that is retrieved by a GraphQL query. I'm able to print it out in console and I can see the array of objects.

```
function ProductsPage(){
    const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(
        gql`
            query{
                getProducts(first: 25, offset: 1) {
                id
            }
            } 
    `, { errorPolicy: 'all' });

    if(loading) return <Layout><p>Loading...</p></Layout>
    if(error){ console.log(error); return <Layout><p>Error...</p></Layout>}
    if(data) { 
        console.log(data.getProducts);
        return(
            <Layout>
                <ul>
                {data.Products.map(function(item){
                    console.log(item);
                    <Product data={item}></Product>
                    })}
                 </ul>
            </Layout>
        )

    }

};
```

And here's the product object:

```
export default function Product(props){
    return(
        <div>
            <p>product:</p>
            <p>{props.data.id}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I can see the array of objects in the console log, and I can also see each object being printed out in console within the map() function.

But the actual product objects never get instantiated - I can check by placing a console.log("hello") in them.

Everything seems like it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the actual product objects never get instantiated

`map()` would need to return `<Product />`.

```
{data.Products.map(function(item){
  console.log(item);
  return <Product data={item} />; // return here
})}
```

or

```
{
  data.Products.map(item => <Product data={item} />)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I would have never figured that. I am used to using React class components and working within the render function. e: can accept your answer in 9 minutes apparently

Comment: @BURGERFLIPPER101 glad to be of help.